# Best way to create a DateTime.now() with only Year, Month, and Day?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

In Flutter/Dart, I want to create a DateTime object based on the current date.

I don't want it to have more precision than the Year, Month, and Day.

Is this the most efficient way to create the object?

```
final today = DateTime(
   DateTime.now().year,
   DateTime.now().month,
   DateTime.now().day
);
```

Comment: I created a class called localdate and another called localtime modelled after the Java classes of the same name. Most apps use just faster or just time a lot so they are work the effort to create.

Comment: If you just care about dates, just use `today = DateTime.now()`.

Comment: If I just use ```today = DateTime.now()```, then ```today``` will have hours, minutes, etc. that will affect calculations in other places where I want discrete comparisons made at the precision level of a whole day.

Answer (score -1):

To format the date to only day, month and year, do as show below:

```
DateTime today = new DateTime.now();
var _today = DateTime.parse(today.toString());
var _formatToday = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(today);
```

Comment: I had to install this package before mind worked
https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install

Comment: The method `.format()` returns a String, not a DateTime.